# DEC "CI" bus, better known as?

Tags: dec, vax

Looking over a list of [various VAX processors](http://www.vaxmacro.de/vcms.html), I noticed a reference to a "CI" bus. Poking about in Google I can only find *very* passing mentions of this, and no details. I suspect this had some other un-acronym name that might work better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a certain point in the 1980s, 'I' things were all the rage in DEC.

BI - Backplane Interconnect (the bus in the 8xxx series VAXen - [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAXBI_Bus))

CI - Computer Interconnect (showed up as star coupler for VAXclusters, also to HSC intelligent storage controllers)

NI - Network Interconnect (ethernet to you).

SI - Storage Interconnect - controller-to-disk.

The point was to define a hierarchy of standardized interconnect structure, with different characteristics of speed, operating area, number of nodes supported, etc.)

[Figure 1-3 in this manual](http://www.vaxhaven.com/images/7/7a/EK-HSCCN-IN-A01.pdf) shows various interconnects, including the CI.

The [DEC Technical Journal, number 5](http://www.dtjcd.vmsresource.org.uk/pdfs/dtj_v01-05_sep1987.pdf), from 1987, has some CI details.

Comment: That "I" nomenclature was mainly used in architectural diagrams (like that Figure 1-3) - it didn't so much mean it was the name of an actual technology (like "MASSbus").  right?

Comment: There was very definitely one definition of the "CI" protocol, just like "NI" meant "Ethernet" (10 Mb/S at the time) and not just any old network interconnect, and "BI" was one specific backplane technology.  From the point of view of a programmer in DEC, CI was the term for a specific technology.  It showed up in product names too: e.g., the CI780 module that plugged into a VAX 11/780 backplane to allow it to be connected up to a star coupler.

Comment: If you look at the [Software Product Description](http://h30266.www3.hpe.com/PDFs/SPDClusters.pdf) for VAX clusters, you'll see *"OpenVMS Cluster software supports any combination
of the following interconnects:
• CI (computer interconnect) (Alpha and VAX) …."*  so it's definitely an actual thing.

Comment: "just like "NI" meant "Ethernet" - gebus, thanks DEC.

Comment: I think you have a sequencing error. First you decide what busses you need, architecturally speaking - so we needed a local area network interconnect (to replace the point to point DDCMP links that DECnet was previously built on).  So that's your "NI".  Then you make a case that the best candidate for NI is Ethernet (though maybe a 10Mb/s Ethernet rather than the existing 4Mb/s Ethernet, I don't know the timing here).